How to deactivate an unused OSGI service?
Apparently Eclipse violates OSGI specification and does not deactivate singleton Components when all no ServiceReferences to it are left.
This happens due to an automatically set framework property
ds.delayed.keepInstances=true

Is there a way for my Eclipse plugin to actually benefit from component lifetime (I'm polling a remote REST endpoint and want to stop doing so, when no clients are left)?
As a workaround I've used
 <service scope="bundle">

in component declaration, but this would create more instances and more polling threads when I'll add more clients form other bundles.
A related discussion, that produces no results.
How can my Component detect that it is no longer used and stop its activity?

What do you mean with "Eclipse violates OSGI"? Do you mean "Equinox violates OSGi" or more specific "Equinox DS violates OSGi"? But Equinox DS was dropped years ago. Also, the things you refer to are years old and do not back up your claims. Please provide a complete minimal reproducible example.

@howlger I literally mean what I said. Felix SCR in an Eclipse application is configured not to deactivate singletons by default.

Your question is based on a wrong assumption. It's up to the Eclipse application whether to set ds.delayed.keepInstances=true or  ds.delayed.keepInstances=false; it is not hard-coded: https://github.com/eclipse-equinox/equinox/blob/cbd261e4ec3c22dd6cfd896fe17532828296283b/bundles/org.eclipse.osgi/container/src/org/eclipse/core/runtime/adaptor/EclipseStarter.java#L220 Please avoid generalization if you have not checked all cases and show a concrete example and make sure to tell the version of each software component used. It is still unclear what you are asking.

@howlger are you saying, that Eclipse will continue to work fine with non-default settings? I explicitly state, that there is a property to control the behavior. Not sure what generalization are you talking about.  The question is how to deactivate unused service. Is it acceptable to change the property? Is there a way to override it for my service?

BTW, I don't think that a plugin shoild change the platform configuration.

Your question sound like an XY problem. How is ds.delayed.keepInstances=true changing the behavior of your code and how does it violates the OSGi specification in which part? To my understanding ds.delayed.keepInstances=true does not free memory by keeping the instance of the service provider (which should not be problem since it's a singleton, right?) and improves a bit performance by avoiding reloading it, right? Each Eclipse-based application can have its own default settings/configuration. And DS didn't exist from the very beginning.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I doubt that the OSGi specification gives the guarantee that the @Deactivate method of the service provider is called immediately after and not at some point after the service is no longer needed. I don't think Apache Felix SCR (which you incorrectly refer to as Eclipse) violates the OSGi specification by providing the mentioned option. Be aware that Eclipse Equinox is the reference implementation of OSGi. In the chat you talked about "polling a remote, heavily loaded REST service" which sounds like you need to implement on your side, e.g. a service to which listener can be added.
